# Independence of two random variables 2

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, independence

> Assume we put points on the two dimensional $x-y$ plane according to Poisson distribution, consider $r_1$ is the location of the closest point to origin and $r_2$ is the location of the second closest point to origin. Are $r_1$ and $r_2$ independent?  How about for a general distribution (not Poisson)?

To solve this, I am thinking of finding the CDF of $r_1$ and $r_2$ and to see if the following holds:

$\mathbb{P}(r_1<x_1 \,\cap r_2<x_2) = \mathbb{P}(r_1<x_1) \mathbb{P} (r_2<x_2)$

My questions:

1. Is this the right path?
2. According to Poisson distribution and its special characteristics, can we find the independence faster?
3. How about the general case where the distribution is not Poisson?

Thanks

Comment: That has to hold for all x1 and x2 I think